# How to restrict Ubuntu to only show LTS updates

Tags: upgrade, updates, 14.04, lts, stable-release-updates

**I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS last week.**
Now I dont want to update daily for all the newly available updates, I want to restrict updates to **only LTS updates**.

**So I have seleted "For long-terms supports versions" for notify me for new Ubuntu Version dropdown in updates tab in "Softwares and Updates" window.**

**Am I correct in these steps?**

Another Question is **how frequently updates are released for a LTS, is it as frequently as daily Ubuntu updates available for "For any new version" ?**

Anyone can help me, answer my queries?
Please...

Comment: You will get updates for 14.04. And you want to get them as they will improve things and fix problems. They may come in daily for a few days and then no updates for a few days. The "For long-term support versions" will not come into play for six months or more when Ubuntu releases the next version. That version will pass you by as it will not be long-term support. The next long-term support version won't be released for another couple of years.

Comment: I haven't understood your point clearly, Please explain your points.

Comment: Can I get updates for **"For long-terms versions"** frequently like around once in a week or once in a a month like that? OR I will get updates once in a year ? Please explain a little bit, please........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’re confused about the difference between *updates* and *upgrades**.

Ubuntu 40.04 LTS is a **long-term support** release. What does that mean? It means that **support** is available **long-term**. And *support*, in this context, means that **updates** are made available to fix bugs. These updates do not (generally) supply new features: they just fix bugs. Some of those bugs are critical, and it is important that you apply the fixes when they become available.

The updates are divided into two categories: “Important Security Updates” and “Recommended Updates”. Generally, when recommended updates become available, you won’t be notified (this depends on your settings, but that’s the default). When important security updates become available, you *will* be notified, and, at this time, will also be notified of any recommended updates you may choose to also apply. If you’re a normal desktop user, your best course is probably to simply take the lot. Very few will have any noticeable effect, but they do keep your computer more secure.

An **upgrade**, on the other hand, means moving to a new release of Ubuntu. The move from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 is an upgrade. This update will come with a slightly different look and feel and a few new features. (Ubuntu is fairly stable these days, so there are fewer *major* differences between releases than there used to be.)

If you were thinking of moving from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS, you should. Ubuntu 13.10 is is not a long-term support release, which means that it is no longer supported, which means that updates are no longer available to fix security-critical bugs. (In fact, currently, the *only* supported Ubuntu releases are LTS releases.)

---

**The practical upshot of all that is,** whatever version of Ubuntu you are on, you will get **updates**. You should apply those updates when they are offered to you. It really is very low hassle.

When your version reaches end-of-life** you will also be offered an **upgrade** to the next version.

---

<sub>* It doesn’t help, perhaps, that `apt-get` also uses these two words, but uses them completely differently. `apt-get update` means “check the repositories for what new updates are available”, and `apt-get upgrade` means “apply any available updates”. Do not let this confuse you: words can have different meanings in different contexts, and as long as they’re clearly defined, this is not a problem.</sub>

<sub>** If you’re on an LTS release, you’ll also be offered an upgrade when the next LTS release comes out. You are, however, under no obligation to take it. Long-term support releases really are long term. Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server Edition is still supported till next year. More recent LTS releases support the desktop edition for that long too.</sub>

Comment: He can however, choose to install security updates only (should be a checkmark in the update settings). This way he can lower the frequent updates a little if he doesn't care for regular updates but still keep his system secure.

Comment: I take both recommended and security updates, but am only notified of updates when a security one comes out. So if a recommended update is available, I won't see it till the next security update is available, at which time I'll take both. I *think* this is the default setup. I certainly don't recall customising it.